# How can I use Convolutional LSTM in Keras to realize position estimation?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I used LSTM in Keras with Tensorflow.

I would like to realize position estimation.

I want to input the movie (1 scene is 15 frame) and estimate the position of moving the square in the movie.

Input is 15 frame. Output is 2 variable (x, y).

In the following code the estimation accuracy is too bad. What should I do?
And, I don't understand AveragePooling3D/Reshape (Without this it will not perform.).

```python
# We create a layer which take as input movies of shape
# (n_frames, width, height, channels) and returns a movie
# of identical shape.

seq = Sequential()
seq.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=40, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                   input_shape=(None, 80, 80, 1),
                   padding='same', return_sequences=True))
seq.add(BatchNormalization())

seq.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=40, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                   padding='same', return_sequences=True))
seq.add(BatchNormalization())

seq.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=40, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                   padding='same', return_sequences=True))
seq.add(BatchNormalization())

seq.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=40, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                   padding='same', return_sequences=True))
seq.add(BatchNormalization())

#seq.add(Flatten())
seq.add(AveragePooling3D((1, 80, 80)))

seq.add(Reshape((-1, 40)))

seq.add(Dense(2))

#seq.add(Conv3D(filters=1, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),
#               activation='sigmoid',
#               padding='same', data_format='channels_last'))

seq.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
def generate_movies(n_samples=1200, n_frames=15):
    row = 80
    col = 80
    noisy_movies = np.zeros((n_samples, n_frames, row, col, 1), dtype=np.float)
    shifted_movies = np.zeros((n_samples, n_frames, row, col, 1),
                              dtype=np.float)
    square_x_y = np.zeros((n_samples, n_frames, 2), dtype=np.float)

    for i in range(n_samples):
        for j in range(1):
            # Initial position
            xstart = np.random.randint(20, 60)
            ystart = np.random.randint(20, 60)
            # Direction of motion
            directionx = np.random.randint(0, 3) - 1
            directiony = np.random.randint(0, 3) - 1

            # Size of the square
            w = np.random.randint(2, 4)

            for t in range(n_frames):
                x_shift = xstart + directionx * t
                y_shift = ystart + directiony * t
                noisy_movies[i, t, x_shift - w: x_shift + w,
                             y_shift - w: y_shift + w, 0] += 1

                # Make it more robust by adding noise.
                # The idea is that if during inference,
                # the value of the pixel is not exactly one,
                # we need to train the network to be robust and still
                # consider it as a pixel belonging to a square.
                if np.random.randint(0, 2):
                    noise_f = (-1)**np.random.randint(0, 2)
                    noisy_movies[i, t,
                                 x_shift - w - 1: x_shift + w + 1,
                                 y_shift - w - 1: y_shift + w + 1,
                                 0] += noise_f * 0.1

                # Shift the ground truth by 1
                x_shift = xstart + directionx * (t + 1)
                y_shift = ystart + directiony * (t + 1)
                shifted_movies[i, t, x_shift - w: x_shift + w,
                               y_shift - w: y_shift + w, 0] += 1

                square_x_y[i, t, 0] = x_shift/row
                square_x_y[i, t, 1] = y_shift/col

    # Cut to a 40x40 window
    #noisy_movies = noisy_movies[::, ::, 20:60, 20:60, ::]
    #shifted_movies = shifted_movies[::, ::, 20:60, 20:60, ::]
    #noisy_movies[noisy_movies >= 1] = 1
    #shifted_movies[shifted_movies >= 1] = 1
    return noisy_movies, shifted_movies, square_x_y

# Train the network
noisy_movies, shifted_movies, sq_x_y = generate_movies(n_samples = 1200)
seq.fit(noisy_movies[:1000], sq_x_y[:1000], batch_size=10,
        epochs=1, validation_split=0.05)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See your `seq.summary()` to understand the shapes.

Your last `ConvLSTM2D` layer is outputting something with shape

- `(movies, length, side1, side2, channels)`
- `(None, None, 80, 80, 40)`

For the Dense layer to work, you will need to keep the "movies" and the "length" dimension, and collapse the others into one.

Notice that the dimension `40` (the channels) is important for it represents different "concepts", while the `80`s (the sides) are purely 2D positional.

Since you don't want to touch the "length" dimension, you need an `AveragePooling2D` (not 3D). But since you're going to detect a very distinct **positional feature** and its **location**, I suggest you don't collapse the spatial dimensions at all. It should be better to just reshape and add a `Dense` that will take into account these positions.

So instead of the `AveragePooling` I suggest you use:

```
seq.add(Reshape((-1, 80*80*40)) #new shape is = (movies, length, 80*80*40)
```

Then you add a Dense layer that still has a notion of the positions:

```
seq.add(Dense(2)) #output shape is (movies, length, 2)
```

---

This is not guaranteed to make your model perform well, but I believe "better".

Other things you can do are adding more dense layers and smoothly go from the 80*80*40 features to 2.

This is more complex, but you might study the functional API model and learn about "U-nets" and try to make something like a u-net there.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation detailed !!! 

I understood well.

I surveyed about "U-net". I may not need architecture this one.
I aim to realize the position estimation with cleary axis-x, y (floating precision).  Thus, it little different from segmentation problem.

Incidentally, the estimation accuracy is terribly bad also after I fixed the program.

Label Position (x, y):
0.56, 0.70

0.56, 0.71
0.56, 0.72
0.56, 0.73
0.56, 0.74
0.56, 0.75
0.56, 0.76...

Estimation Position (x, y):
0.48, 0.44
0.47, 0.40
0.48, 0.39
0.47, 0.41
0.48, 0.43
0.50, 0.48
0.60, 0.51...

Comment: I got very-high accuracy!!!!!!!!
Learning time was overwhelmingly short.